# garbled items in a horizontal list with css

Tags: css, layout, list

I have made a page in which i m using a list to display the items horizontally

Now i can see the result in the page [here](http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/newpeople.jsp)

But when i drag and make the browser window short i get a garbled list
as in the scrren-shot here

http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/people_ss.JPG

http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/people_ss.JPG

I m using a css in the list as : -

```
#navlist li
        {

            padding: 1em;
            float: left;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
```

at the end of the list i m using a clearing div

```
#clear-both 
{
   clear: both;
}
```

Any help

Thanks

Pradyut

[2]:   [2]: http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/people_ss.JPG

Comment: updated page... http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/people.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well could solve the problem using a min-height in the another div css

```
  #another 
  {
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: green;
      min-height: 75px;
  }
```

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to access your site.

Try using display:inline instead of float:left

```
#navlist li
{
padding-right: 1em;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the varying heights of each LI element.  If you give them all a common height, the layout flows properly when the window is resized:

```
#navlist li
{
    height: 100px;
    padding: 1em;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: well another question...
how can i align the names to the top such that they are at the same height as that of the images